# Script for uploading web files (via links in Google Spreadsheet) to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to write script for Google Spreadsheet which will upload all files linked in column A (only URLs) to specific folder (which name is written in column B).

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBOP0.png)

I'm partially succesfull. **I can upload first linked file. But I don't know how to edit this script to upload all the files.** Where am I wrong?

This script was found [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19757-download-files-google-drive-google-script) and edited by me.

```
function downloadFile() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pokus");
     var fileURLs = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
     var foldernames = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

     for (i = 0; i < fileURLs.length; i++) {

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURLs[i], {muteHttpExceptions: true});
      var rc = response.getResponseCode();

      if (rc == 200) {

        var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
        var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldernames[i]).next();
        if (folder != null) {
          var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
          fileName = file.getName();
          fileSize = file.getSize();
        }
     }

      var fileInfo = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
      return fileInfo;
    }

    }
```

I'm beginner in writing scripts and I'm not experienced. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

- There is `return fileInfo;` in for loop. So at 1st loop, it's returned from the function. By this, only first linked file can be uploaded.
- All information can be retrieved by modifying `fileInfo` to an array.

### Modified script :

```
function downloadFile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pokus");
  var fileURLs = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var foldernames = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var fileInfo = []; // Added
  for (i = 0; i < fileURLs.length; i++) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURLs[i], {muteHttpExceptions: true});
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();
    if (rc == 200) {
      var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
      var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldernames[i]).next();
      if (folder != null) {
        var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
        fileName = file.getName();
        fileSize = file.getSize();
      }
    }
    fileInfo.push({ "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize }); // Modified
  }
  return fileInfo; // Modified
}
```

### Note :

When there are many upload files, an error might occur.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Břeťa Welcome. Thank you, too.